# Disabling/Enabling user selection in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

So let's say I have the following code and I want to be able to select everything in box2 but make everything else in my body unselectable. The example below works perfectly for chrome, but unfortunately does not work at all in IE. This is because in IE you have to place the "unselectable" attribute on in every single child element. Now obviously I could create a JS function to add this to every element I need it on but my DOM is much much more complex and therefore this would be unrealistic. How could I do this in IE?

```js
            $('body').addClass('unselectable');
            $('body').attr("unselectable", "on");
            $('.box2').addClass('box-selectable');
            $('.box2').attr("unselectable", "off");
```

```css
.unselectable{
   -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}

.selectable{
   -ms-user-select: auto;
   -moz-user-select: auto;
   -khtml-user-select: auto;
   -webkit-user-select: auto;
   user-select: auto;
}

.box-selectable{
   -ms-user-select: auto !important;
   -moz-user-select: auto !important;
   -khtml-user-select: auto !important;
   -webkit-user-select: auto !important;
   user-select: auto ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class='box1'>
  <p> Hello </p>
  <p> World </p>
 </div>
 <div class='box2'>
  <p> Foo </p>
  <p> Bar </p>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually if I try this code snippet out in IE I'm not able to select anything. So perhaps it does work for child elements, but in fact I'm just not able to select anything so my actual question is how can I make box2 selectable if my body tag has an unselectable?

Comment: If I change .box-selectable -ms-user-select: text then it kind of works... I can't highlight box 1. But if start out highlighting in box2 I can continue highlighting to box1.

Comment: Does your code snippet work in Firefox?